# Customize a simple UITableViewCell efficiently

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-efficient

I would like to customize a simple **UITableViewCell** so that I run the customization *only once* and add values (e.g., cell title) later. My app's cell is more complex - it has subviews and uses auto layout; however, a simple example, I believe, will help in focusing on the objective.

I am using iOS 8, Xcode 6.X, Objective-C and Nibs (no storyboard) to keep it simple. I have not created a custom class for **UITableViewCell**. Instead, I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;  //FIXED VALUE FOR EXAMPLE'S SAKE
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;  //FIXED VALUE FOR EXAMPLE'S SAKE
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@"cell == nil");

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //CUSTOMIZING CELL THAT I WANT TO RUN ONLY ONCE
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    NSArray *numbersArray = @[@1,@2,@3];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", numbersArray[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell == nil
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell == nil
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell == nil
```

**FIRST QUESTION:** Why is `cell == nil` run 3 times? It seems wasteful to run the customization code `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` 3 times.

Now, when I enable:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Instead of:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

I get the output:

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

**SECOND QUESTION:** Why isn't `cell == nil` run at all?

**FINAL QUESTIONS:** How can I make `cell == nil` run only once so that I format the UITableViewCell only once? Is there a better way to customize a simple cell, running the customization code only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is cell == nil run 3 times? It seems wasteful to run the customization code cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 3 times.

The table view most likely displays three cells at once, hence requiring three distinct cell objects.

> Why isn't cell == nil run at all?

The documentation states that `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` always returns a valid cell if you registered the identifier previously. It basically takes care of checking if a new cell is required for you.

> How can I make cell == nil run only once so that I format the UITableViewCell only once?

You don't. You will have to customize every single instance. I would recommend to use a custom subclass though, rather then messing with `UITableViewCell` from the outside.

Comment: Thanks Chistian. If I create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, the customization code will still run 3 times if the 3 cells are displayed at once, correct?

Comment: Yes, but this absolutely has to be done. 3 views being visible at once requires 3 distinct instances of the view.

Comment: Cells (or any views in general) can only be reused once scrolled offscreen, hence not being visible to the user any more.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the code `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` in `viewDidLoad` is necessary in order to guarantee the cell reutilization?

Comment: You can fall back to the old `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and manually check if you need to create a new cell. If you want UIKit to do the job for you though, you will have to register a cell class and use `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead. Then again, since UIKit does the job for you, you will not be able to tell when a new cell is created in the view controller itself. You really should create a `UITableViewCell` subclass for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will follow your suggestion. However, I am having problems registering my custom cell. When I add `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` to `viewDidLoad`, I get the error message `Could not load NIB in bundle`. Is the registering code incorrect?

Comment: I have never worked - and will never work - with nibs. Can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is to create a custom class for your cell, and do any customization that isn't dependent on the indexPath there. Usually, I do this in `initWithCoder` or `awakeFromNib`. You should register the nib in `viewDidLoad`; I don't see anything wrong with the code you mention in your comment to Christian's answer, unless the name of the file is wrong. It really isn't the view controller's business to be adding subviews or customizing your cell; that code belongs in the cell's class.

BTW, this doesn't keep the customization code from running multiple times. It needs to run once for each cell instance that you create, just like it does in your original code. The number of cells created will be equal to the number that fit on the screen at one time (plus one maybe).